# Void task with generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to reuse the following static generic `Profile` function in my application:

```
private static async Task<T> Profile<T>(Func<Task<T>> func, string operation)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{operation} is called");
    return await func();
}
```

And I have the following interface to implement:

```
public interface ICustomerOperations
{
    Task<Customer> GetCustomerAsync(string id);

    Task DeleteCustomerAsync(string id);
}
```

I can use `Profile` method with `GetCustomerAsync` without any problem.

```
public async Task<Customer> GetCustomer(string id)
{
    return await Profile(() => _customerOperations.GetCustomerAsync(id), $"GetCustomerAsync");
}
```

However when I try to use `Profile` with `DeleteCustomerAsync`

```
public async void DeleteCustomer(string id)
{
    await Profile(() => _customerOperations.DeleteCustomerAsync(id), $"DeleteCustomerAsync");
}
```

Build failed:

> The type arguments for method 'CrmService.Profile(Func<Task>,
> string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type
> arguments explicitly.

So my question is how can I reuse `Task<T>` with `void`?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't. The `Func` delegate was introduced to support a return value. A `void` doesn't have a return value. You will need another `Profile` method that accepts a parameter of the `Action` delegate.

Comment: What is the point to have a method like `Profile` (btw it is a terrible name in my opinion)? Why do you need that?

Comment: @PeterCsala This is just an example, I simplified it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to duplicate your method:

```
private static async Task Profile(Func<Task> func, string operation)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{operation} is called");
    await func();
}
```

I think duplicating your method is cleaner than doing some hacks like this:

```
public async void DeleteCustomer(string id)
{
    await Profile(async () => { await _customerOperations.DeleteCustomerAsync(id); return 0; }, $"DeleteCustomerAsync");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering is it possible to do that without duplicating method?

Comment: I showed you also the possbility with an async labmda that returns an arbitrary value. But if the `Profile` method you showed us is really your code and not some shortened version, I would prefer duplicating it. Of course, this might look different if you have dozens of lines of code in it.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an overload without duplicating the method:

```
private static Task Profile(Func<Task> func, string operation)
{
  return Profile<object>(async () => { await func(); return null; }, operation);
}
```